# Can't access page served by docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container

I've just started a tutorial on Docker and I've created a container identical to the one [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#define-a-container-with-dockerfile). Creating the container works fine, it pulls all the dependencies it needs for python, pushing to docker hub works fine as well.

I then run the container using the following command:

```
docker run -p 4000:80 username/get-started:part2
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I access localhost:4000, it says it refuses to connect. On a different thread, I saw the command `docker-machine` being mentioned. Gave that a try, this is the result.

```
docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default            virtualbox   Timeout

docker-machine ip default
Error getting IP address: Host is not running

docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
881e9a9ebf21        username/get-started:part2   "python app.py"     21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->4000/tcp   happy_raman
```

I am running Docker on Windows 10 64 bits and I'm using the `Docker Toolbox Terminal`.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Running 'docker ps' lists the active container that I just started.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `docker ps` or `docker container ls` ?

Comment: See updated post .I would expect http, not tcp though.

Comment: This is already an issue for docker on windows. But people fixed that by some workaround. See https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/204#issuecomment-352180129

Comment: Ugh.. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You are most welcome. And after study on that issue, there I saw couple solutions. If any solutions work for you, please post it here so we all can know about that too.

Answer (score 0):

First you can get the docker machine IP:
1. Using command `docker-machine` : `docker-machine ip` 
2.or By login to the docker image and getting the eth1 ip

Then try : [docker-machine ip]:4000